# How to change Image src for Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images on my page, but they're all the same image. I'd like to know how I can change them all with jQuery. Below is what I currently have setup.

I have each image with an ID like `image-1`, `image-2`, etc. and to change them I use

```
$("#image-1").attr({src:"..."});
$("#image-2").attr({src:"..."});
```

Is there a way I can just set my ID to `myTag` and then change the image src for every image with that id? Because if I were to do this when the method i have now, it'll only change the first image with that id.

Comment: Can you instead apply a class to the images, to group them all together?

Comment: "every image with that ID" - IDs should really be unique, even if browsers are lenient.

Comment: And what form does the `src` take?

Comment: *Well*, technically...if you refuse to follow the rules of HTML (or if you don't have control over the markup), you can do `$('[id="image-1"]').attr("src", "...")` to change multiple elements with the same id attribute. That's a workaround, but ideally your IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use a `class` rather than an `id`.  If you use `class="imageClass"` and reference the `class` in your jQuery it should work.

```
$(".imageClass").attr("src", "imagename");
```

The principle behind this is that an id should be unique whereas a class should be used for referencing multiple tags.  You can have an id and a class on the same tag, but the id should be unique.  For example, if you want all your headers to be green, you could do:

```
<h1 class="green-header">Text</h1>
```

But if you wanted to change one div in your site to center the text, you could do:

```
<div id="center-text">Text</div>
```

Comment: Probably useful to note that you can have the class as an addition to the id tags, not only as a replacement

Answer (score 1):

Try [^ attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('img[id^="image-"]').prop("src", "imagename");
```

---

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("img[id*='image-']").attr({src:"..."});
```